# Как сделать мерж чтобы предпочтения при конфликте отдавались изменениям полученным с репозитория?

Tags: git, git-merge

Или более свежим коммитам. Конфликтов очень много и не охота править их ручками. Тем более что они на сервере где нет графического интерфейса.

Answer (score 3):

Есть несколько стратегий разрешений конфликтов при слиянии. Думаю, вам подойдёт cтратегия **theirs**. Например, такая команда сольёт изменения и в случае конфликтов возьмёт код из указанной ветки.

```
git merge -Xtheirs их_ветка
```

Подробнее можно почитать в книге «[Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5#_%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B9_%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8_%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B9)».

Answer (score -1):

```
git fetch
git merge origin/master -X theirs
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте в ваш ответ описание кода, чтобы пользователям было легче его понять. Для редактирования ответа, нажмите [Edit]. Так же можете ознакомиться с советами о том, [как написать хороший ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). - [Из очереди проверок](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/148366)